# TK drag&drop: Unable to load tkdnd library

Tags: python, tkinter, drag-and-drop, tcl

I am not able to run TkDnD
I am using Python 3.10.6 with Win 10 in an virtual environment. I tried to follow the instructions in
https://pythonguides.com/python-tkinter-drag-and-drop/
i.e. copying

1. TkinterDnD2 folder inside the Python/lib/site-packages (in my case C:\Users\my_user\my_python\my_env2\Lib\site-packages)
2. tkdnd2.8 folder inside the Python/tcl folder (in my case C:\Users\my_user\my_python\my_env2\tcl)

But there is no tcl folder in \my_env2. Creating  the folder does not work. pip install tcl did not help. A tcl folder was created in lib/site-packages, but copying tkdnd2.8 there did not work.

What can I do?

**Edit**
In a conda environment I found the path where to copy tkdnd2.8:

C:\Users\my_user\miniconda3\envs\spyder-env2\Library\lib
but still, in my venv outside conda I can't find the correct directory.

**Edit 2**

Thanks to @acw1668 ! I installed tkinterdnd2 via pip, which worked fine, but unfortunately, other issues came up:

1. The pip installed tkinterdnd package is lower case, while the manually installed package is camel case (TkinterDnD2), which gave an error that was easy to fix.
2. The test script, which works fine in a spyder environment with manual installation of tkdnd as described above, does not work in the pip installed venv environment. It opens a gui (which is more than it did previously) but the d&d does not work.

Remark: When creating a new spyder environment in miniconda and installing tkinterdnd2 via conda it is also not working, unless I copy the tkdnd2.8 folder in the Library\lib directory.

The script is (basically a simplified version of the one given here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JIy0QjwQBl0):

```
from tkinter import *
from TkinterDnD2 import *


def show_text(event):
    textarea.delete("1.0","end")
    if event.data.endswith(".txt"):
        with open(event.data, "r") as file:
            for line in file:
                line=line.strip()
                textarea.insert("end",f"{line}\n")

ws = TkinterDnD.Tk()
ws.title('PythonGuides')
ws.geometry('400x300')
ws.config(bg='#fcb103')

frame = Frame(ws)
frame.pack()

textarea = Text(frame, height=18, width=40)
textarea.pack(side=LEFT)
textarea.drop_target_register(DND_FILES)
textarea.dnd_bind('<<Drop>>', show_text)

sbv = Scrollbar(frame, orient=VERTICAL)
sbv.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

textarea.configure(yscrollcommand=sbv.set)
sbv.config(command=textarea.yview)

ws.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can simply install the `tkinterdnd2` package via `pip` in your virtual environment.

Comment: It works fine after changing the line `from TkinterDnD2 import *` to `from tkinterdnd2 import TkinterDnD, DND_FILES`.